# Change x axis labels to character in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a line plot with two lines, with x axis being the date. As shown in the picture below using the code here:

[image]

```
date_col <- paste0("2018-01-0", 1:9)

col1 <- runif(9)
col2 <- runif(9)

df <- as.data.frame( cbind(date_col, col1, col2) )
df$date_col <- as.Date(df$date_col)
colnames(df) <- c("Date" ,  "Col1", "Col2")



df$Col1 <- as.numeric(as.vector(df$Col1))
df$Col2 <- as.numeric(as.vector(df$Col2))

axis_size = 10
legend_size = 10
title_size = 12
line_size = 1
caption_size=10

meltdta <- melt(df, id = "Date")


plotobj <- ggplot(meltdta, aes(x=Date, y=value, color=variable) )+
  geom_line(size=line_size)+ylab("Level") + theme_bw() + 
  ggtitle("trial") + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=axis_size),
        legend.position = "bottom")


print(plotobj)
```

I now want to change the date labels on the x axis to be Q0, Q1, Q2 ... to Q8. I wonder how I can do this? I have tried:

```
plotobj + scale_x_discrete(labels=paste0("Q", 0:8) )
```

before printing the object, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried added this line:

```
df[, "Date"] <- paste0("Q", 0:8)
```

before the line

```
df$Col1 <- as.numeric(as.vector(df$Col1))
```

but it produced an empty figure as shown below, the error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. `scale_x_discrete` won't work, as the data isn't discrete (it's Date).

You can force the use of specific labels in `scale_x_date`:

```
plotobj+
   scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), 
                             as.Date("2018-01-09"), 
                             by = "1 day"), 
                labels = paste0("Q", 0:8))
```